# Function that will add any numeric types in swift 4

Tags: swift, generics

Why does this work in swift 4.2?

```
func add<T: Numeric>(num1: T, num2: T) -> T {
    return num1 + num2
}
print(add(num1: 6, num2: 6.7))
```

But this does not work in swift 4.2?

```
var numOne: Int = 6
var numTwo: Double = 6.7
add(num1: numOne, num2: numTwo)
```

These are exactly the same other than putting a number in the function directly I am first storing it in a variable and then passing it to the function.

I would like to write a function in swift 4.2 that can take two of either Double, Int, or Float, and just add them together, how would one accomplish this?

Comment: Consider that generic `T` means always *the same type* when calling the function.

Comment: Yes but numeric is a protocol so T can be an Int for one number and a Double for the other because both conform to the Numeric Protocol in swift if my understanding is correct, so that doesn't explains why this is not working.

Comment: No, at the moment you call the function  `T` can be any type conforming to `Numeric`, but `num1` and `num2` (and the return type) must be the **same** type. That's the behavior of generics.

Comment: And apart from that the `+` operator requires the same operand type anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`numOne` is `Int` type, so the `num2` was inferred as `Int`.

I think you could just make sure the two numbers are the same type before calling `add`.

For type `Double`, `Int`, `Float`, you can just convert them all to `Double` in case not lost precision.

Comment: If that is true, then why isn't num2 in the first function call being inferred as Int as well because there, num1 is also and Int? The purpose of the function is so that you don't have to make sure the arguments are the same type. I want a function in which i can put in Int, Float, Double, and the function will add them even if they are different types.

Comment: **There is no inference**. A generic type means *any type* but currently **one** static type